# Query result optimization

Tags: soql, class, apex, governorlimits

I have a custom object Call2_vod__c which is detail of Account. There might be 100 calls for one Account. I need any one call record with that Account. How should I do the query?
Please find my piece of code here, getting Apex CPU time limit exception.

Apex class:

```
global class Account_chk {
  WebService static void method1(Id i) {
  List<Call2_vod__c> a= new List<Call2_vod__c>();
  List<Attachment> p=new List<Attachment> ();
  List<Attachment> exist=new List<Attachment> ();
  exist=[select ParentId,id from Attachment];

  Map<Id, Attachment> existMap = new Map<Id, Attachment>();
  Map<Id,Call2_vod__c> signMap = new Map<Id, Call2_vod__c>();

  for (Attachment att : exist) {
    existMap.put(att.ParentId, att);
  }

  for (Call2_vod__c call: [select Id,Signature_vod__c,Account_vod__c from Call2_vod__c where Signature_Date_vod__c !=Null and Account_vod__c not in :existMap.keySet()])
  {    
    Attachment record = new Attachment(Name = Call.Id ,ParentId = call.Account_vod__c , Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature_vod__c), ContentType = 'image/jpeg');
    if (record.parentId !=Null ) {
      p.add(record);
    }     
  }

  try {
    insert(p);
  } catch(System.DMLException e) {
    System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
  }
}
}
```

Comment: The first query in your code queries every Attachment in the org; that query needs a where clause to get the numbers down to something within governor limits. Can it be filtered by the ID passed in to your method?

Comment: Hi Keith! The id passed in method is of a single account. There is command button shown in each account page which calls this class and the id of the account is passed.But I need result sets for all accounts so I can't use this id.

Comment: You will need to re-think your approach here: you cannot synchronously process what could me millions of Attachments on a button click.

Comment: If Call2_VOD__c is a detail of account, why do you need attachment results for other accounts? not sure we understand your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see is that you are querying and then iterating over all the attachments in your org. The second is that your second query is not selective. You have a != and a not in which are expensive.

You are probably hitting the CPU time limit because you are querying all attachments in your org. Take the account Id coming into your service and query for attachments with that account id as the parent Id.

Comment: Hi Pick! The first query with List exist catches if there are Accounts already in attachment object which has already signatures attached. If so those Accounts should not come under second query to avoid duplicate signatures of same account. Please let me know if you need further info regarding this.

Comment: You are probably hitting the CPU time limit because you are querying all attachments in your org. Take the account Id coming into your service and query for attachments with that account id as the parent Id